# How do I send my gganimate html animation to a colleague?

Tags: r, ggplot2, gganimate

I have made an animation using `gganimate`, and output it using the command:

```
gganimate(p, 'tmp_20161220_animation_output.html')
```

I can see that this file is in my working directory. However, when I open the source of the html page I don't see where it is getting the animation files from. I am sure if I just emailed my colleague this html file the animations will not work on their computer. What should I do to enable sharing of my animation?

Source of html file, note that while images seem to be stored in a `images` subdirectory, no where in this code is this directory referenced:

```
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="generator" content="R package animation 2.4">
    <title>Animations Using the R Language</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/reset.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/styles.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/scianimator.css" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/highlight.js/8.3/styles/github.min.css">

    <script src="js/jquery-1.4.4.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/jquery.scianimator.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/highlight.js/8.3/highlight.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/highlight.js/8.3/languages/r.min.js"></script>
  <script>hljs.initHighlightingOnLoad();</script>

</head>
<body>

    <div class="scianimator"><div id="Rplot" style="display: inline-block;"></div></div>
    <div class="scianimator" style="width: 480px; text-align: left"><pre><code class="r">## Animations generated in R version 3.3.2 (2016-10-31)
##   using the package animation
library(gganimate)
library(data.table)
library(dplyr)
library(purrr)
library(readr)
library(tidyr)
library(tibble)
library(ggplot2)
library(tidyverse)
library(RPostgreSQL)
library(DBI)
expr
## R version 3.3.2 (2016-10-31)
## Platform: x86_64-w64-mingw32/x64 (64-bit)
## Other packages: gganimate 0.1, data.table 1.10.0, dplyr 0.5.0, purrr 0.2.2, readr 1.0.0, tidyr 0.6.0, tibble 1.2, ggplot2
## 2.2.0, tidyverse 1.0.0, RPostgreSQL 0.4-1, DBI 0.5-1</code></pre></div>
    <script src="js/Rplot.js"></script>
<!-- highlight R code -->

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I would not be so sure it wouldn't work. I can email r-markdown generated html files with embedded rgl files - rgl 3dplots with which you can change the viewing angle interactively. Of course it is a big html file. Did you look at the size and compare it to the size of your animation? And then maybe leave it out and see how the size changes?

Comment: it is not embedded. The images are in a separate image directory. The file size is 2 KB. In addition, the script components and css are also in separate directories. Note that this code is not generated using `rmarkdown`. I have a separate issue with the version generated with `rmarkdown` which I am also trying to fix.

Comment: In the past I've saved animations from `gganimate` as both .gif and .mp4, which allowed me to email them to others.